# Take uploaded files on plone and download them via a python script?

Tags: python, pdf, blob, ocr, plone

I created a document site on plone from which file uploads can be made.  I saw that plone saves them in the filesystem in the form of a blob, now I need to take them through a python script that will process the pdfs downloaded with an OCR.  Does anyone have any idea how to do it?  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how to extract PDFs from BLOB-storage or if it's possible at all, but you can extract them from a running Plone-site (e.g. executing the script via a browser-view):

```
import os
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName

def isPdf(search_result):
    """Check mime_type for Plone >= 5.1, otherwise check file-extension."""
    if mimeTypeIsPdf(search_result) or search_result.id.endswith('.pdf'):
        return True
    return False


def mimeTypeIsPdf(search_result):
    """
    Plone-5.1 introduced the mime_type-attribute on files.
    Try to get it, if it doesn't exist, fail silently.
    Return True if mime_type exists and is PDF, otherwise False.
    """
    try:
        mime_type = search_result.mime_type
        if mime_type == 'application/pdf':
            return True
    except:
        pass
    return False


def exportPdfFiles(context, export_path):
    """
    Get all PDF-files of site and write them to export_path on the filessytem.
    Remain folder-structure of site.
    """
    catalog = getToolByName(context, 'portal_catalog')
    search_results = catalog(portal_type='File', Language='all')
    for search_result in search_results:
        # For each PDF-file:
        if isPdf(search_result):
            file_path = export_path + search_result.getPath()
            file_content = search_result.getObject().data
            parent_path = '/'.join(file_path.split('/')[:-1])
            # Create missing directories on the fly:
            if not os.path.exists(parent_path):
                os.makedirs(parent_path)
            # Write PDF:
            with open(file_path, 'w') as fil:
                fil.write(file_content)
                print 'Wrote ' + file_path

    print 'Finished exporting PDF-files to ' + export_path
```

The example keeps the folder-structure of the Plone-site in the export-directory. If you want them flat in one directory, a handler for duplicate file-names is needed.

Comment: De nada, have a great export-time!